# Decrease size of display used in Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display

The screen of my Macbook pro cracked from the bottom left, and vertical + horizontal lines appeared. While waiting to repair it, is there any way to decrease the used space from the display to fit only in the non-damaged area?

For example 90% width (right to left), 90% height (top to bottom).

[image]

Comment: I’ve added some helpful links to screen sharing apps on the main question for this issue. Nothing has changed software wise on this front or hardware wise since the first version of OS X. Your photo is excellent in explaining this sort of damage! +1

Comment: @bmike well actually it seems to be possible with SwitchResX?