# Using SwitchResX to shrink active width/height of retina display

Tags: display, resolution

I have broken my Macbook pro display, and part of it became invisible.

I found this application [SwitchResX](https://www.madrau.com/) in which I could define custom resolutions and set some settings  that decrease the active height and width.

[image]

Unfortunately I could not manage to get the correct settings (especially not the scan rate and pixel clock)..

Does anyone have any experience with this?

My laptop's screen is retina 15", and my resolution is 1440 x 900 @ 60hz

[image]

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/235115/85275 https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/382230/85275 & https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/415093/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin In the first link, he's saying "There is also a third-party application that could possibly be useful. It's called SwitchResX." That's what I am trying to use. But he's not giving any clues on how.. :(